# Is Blaise Zabini's mother a serial killer?

Tags: harry-potter

...or maybe a victim of circumstance /a curse?

If I recall the lady is infamous for the trail of dead husbands she left behind.

Did JKR speak about this in her interviews, or perhaps the name Blaise is a reference to a past murder case?

Comment: "*It was as Harry had suspected. Everyone here seemed to have been invited because they were connected to somebody well-known or influential – everyone except Ginny. Zabini, who was interrogated after McLaggen, turned out to have a famously beautiful witch for a mother (from what Harry could make out, she had been married seven times, each of her husbands dying mysteriously and leaving her mounds of gold)."* - Half Blood Prince

Comment: since my previous comment was deleted, "sounds like its just a typical black widow story" https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlackWidow trope

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## We don’t really know if she killed her husbands or not for sure.

Blaise Zabini’s mother is only mentioned once, when Zabini attends the Slug Club meeting. There’s nothing stated either way in the seven books or any other sources about her or her husbands. She’s mentioned to have had seven husbands, who each died mysteriously and left her gold. She was famous for her beauty, which was probably how she was able to get seven husbands, but we don’t have any confirmation if she was actively involved in causing any of their deaths.

> “Everyone here seemed to have been invited because they were connected to somebody well-known or influential – everyone except Ginny. Zabini, who was interrogated after McLaggen, turned out to have a famously beautiful witch for a mother (from what Harry could make out, she had been married seven times, each of her husbands dying mysteriously and leaving her mounds of gold).” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 7 (The Slug Club)*</sup></sub>

It certainly sounds like she might have, but that’s not definitive proof. Sirius Black was seen laughing at the scene where 12 Muggles and Pettigrew were ‘killed’, but he was actually innocent. Zabini’s mother could be a similarly unfortunate person, or she could be killing her husbands for their money - we don’t know. We can assume she’s not a convicted criminal, since Slughorn was unwilling to accept a relative of a Death Eater, he’d likely reject the son of a known or heavily suspected killer as well, so there probably isn’t overwhelming evidence that she’d done it.

> “I wouldn’t bank on an invitation,’ said Zabini. ‘He asked me about Nott’s father when I first arrived. They used to be old friends, apparently, but when he heard he’d been caught at the Ministry he didn’t look happy, and Nott didn’t get an invitation, did he? I don’t think Slughorn’s interested in Death Eaters.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 7 (The Slug Club)*</sup></sub>

However, that doesn’t prove she didn’t do it. She could have just not gotten caught, or managed to convince people of her innocence when she actually was guilty. It’s left as unclear what happened to Zabini’s mother’s husbands, so we don’t know for sure if she killed them and got away with it.